# NServiceBus IMessageModule per message

Tags: nhibernate, nservicebus

I have to construct NHibernate Session from multiple SessionFactory based on a property inside Message, I think I could use IMessageModule to handle the begin of message processing but it doesn't have any argument and I don't know if it's possible to access current message being handled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the headers using the static Bus.CurrentMessageContext.Headers property

More here:

https://github.com/NServiceBus/NServiceBus/blob/v2.5/Samples/FullDuplex/MyClient/ClientEndpoint.cs

Comment: I don't see any static class called Bus.  The code sample that you link to has a class with an instance property named Bus.  I'm not following how this gets the current message into an IMessageModule.

Comment: Messagemodules has di as well so just add a IBus dependency to your message module